# Appium driver.find_element() returns Dictionary [Error]

Tags: python, appium, ui-automation, appium-desktop

Appium verison: 2.1.4
Selenium version: 4.0.0

**driver.find_element()** returns a dictionary instead of an element object, so while doing **driver.find_element().click()** the following error is thrown.

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'click'

Similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374696/appium-driver-find-element-reutrn-dict-instead-of-webelement) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1638)

But the fix didnt work. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to solve this without updating Appium:

```
if type(element) is dict:
    first_element = list(element.values())[0]
    element = driver.create_web_element(element_id=first_element)
```